# I want to install the react native app on our company phones (between 50 - 100)

Tags: react-native, deployment

Which is the best and hopefully the simplest way to install my react native application to the company phones (both iPhone and Android) There are about 50 to 100 phones that the company gave out to the users.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a big subject. Check Ad Hoc distribution / private unlisted distribution. Diawi maybe ? Why don't you just deploy the app to the stores and have them download it?

Comment: Just want to keep the app private.  may have some confidential info within the app.

Comment: Diawi could be what I was looking for.